# can I switch the grouping variable in a single dplyr statement?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Here's a simple example to illustrate the issue:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = c(1,1,2,2), b = 1:2)

dt[, c := cumsum(a), by = b][, d := cumsum(a), by = c]
#   a b c d
#1: 1 1 1 1
#2: 1 2 1 2
#3: 2 1 3 2
#4: 2 2 3 4
```

Attempting to do the same in `dplyr` I fail because the first `group_by` is persistent and the grouping is by both `b` and `c`:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,2), b = 1:2)

df %.% group_by(b) %.% mutate(c = cumsum(a)) %.%
       group_by(c) %.% mutate(d = cumsum(a))
#  a b c d
#1 1 1 1 1
#2 1 2 1 1
#3 2 1 3 2
#4 2 2 3 2
```

Is this a bug or a feature? If it's a feature, then how would one replicate the `data.table` solution in a single statement?

Comment: Actually with the newer `dplyr` versions you code will work correctly because `dplyr` drops aggregation level per each `mutate`/`summarise` operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
> df %>% group_by(b) %>% mutate(c = cumsum(a)) %>%
+        group_by(c) %>% mutate(d = cumsum(a))
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: c

  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
2 1 2 1 2
3 2 1 3 2
4 2 2 3 4
```

**Update**

With newer version of dplyr use `%>%` rather than `%.%` and `ungroup` is no longer needed (as per David Arenburg's comment).

Comment: thanks, a sideways related question - any idea why `df %.% group_by(b) %.% summarise(cumsum(a))` doesn't work (and how to make that work)?

Comment: Use `mutate` like this:  `df %.% group_by(b) %.% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(a))`

Comment: thanks, I guess a better example of the issue is how would one replicate `dt[, rep(a, 3), by = b]`?

Comment: @eddi Not sure if this is what you are asking but ... mutate produces a variable as long as the data. summarise produces a variable as long as the number of groups. When I tried your code with a data.frame or a data.table as input I got a different result in both 0.1.1 and the development version. See this [issue on github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/258)

Comment: @Vincent I added a new question about it - http://stackoverflow.com/q/21737815/817778

Comment: You can also use `group_by(c, add = F)`

Comment: And it's a deliberate feature - I think it makes the most common case easier with the known tradeoff that it makes some things harder to express.

Comment: Actually you don't need `ungroup` here at all. This question/answer is outdated. At least in its current format.