# grouped operations that result in length not equal to 1 or length of group in dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm not sure which function to use to do the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = 1:4, b = 1:2)

dt[, rep(a[1], 3), by = b]
#   b V1
#1: 1  1
#2: 1  1
#3: 1  1
#4: 2  2
#5: 2  2
#6: 2  2
```

Both `summarise` and `mutate` are unhappy with this length:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:2)

df %.% group_by(b) %.% summarise(rep(a[1], 3))
#Error: expecting a single value

df %.% group_by(b) %.% mutate(rep(a[1], 3))
#Error: incompatible size (3), expecting 2 (the group size) or 1
```

Comment: Don't know if it helps but using your `dplyr` code with a `data.table` works and with `plyr` you can do that too with a `data.frame`.

Comment: @dickoa thanks, that's interesting (fwiw this is mostly just an exercise for me to understand how to use `dplyr` - I don't really see the point of using it with a `data.table`); sounds like a bug in `summarise` then

Comment: See https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154

Comment: +1 This is an interesting difference; hopefully the final solution allows arbitrary return lengths for any groups.

Comment: In this case `df %>% group_by(b) %>% slice(rep(1, 3))` works fine. For rowwise operations, where each row returns an arbitrary number of values, you can use the `df %>% mutate(new = map(old, f)) %>% unnest()` idiom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `dplyr` version 0.2 you could do this using the `do` operator:

```
> df %>% group_by(b) %>% do(data.frame(a = rep(.$a[1], 3)))
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#Groups: b
#
#  b a
#1 1 1
#2 1 1
#3 1 1
#4 2 2
#5 2 2
#6 2 2
```

Comment: +1 for showing me what `do` can do (though note comments in my "answer")

Answer (score 7):

While @beginneR's answer does work, it doesn't seem to be a real substitute to the `data.table` behavior.  Consider:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = rep(1:1e4, 2))
dt <- data.table(df)
microbenchmark(times=5,
  dt[, rep(a[1], 3), by = b],
  df %>% group_by(b) %>% do(data.frame(a = rep(.$a[1], 3)))
)
```

has the `dplyr` implementation >200x slower.

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                      expr        min         lq     median         uq
                                dt[, rep(a[1], 3), by = b]   13.14318   13.70248   14.60524   15.26676
 df %>% group_by(b) %>% do(data.frame(a = rep(.$a[1], 3))) 3269.40731 3359.11614 3583.19430 3736.67162
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this with `do` that doesn't require calling `data.frame` each `do`?  Also, the syntax is a bit involved for what is something very simple in `data.table`.

Otherwise, as per **[Hadley's issue link](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154)**, it seems this is expected to be implemented in `dplyr` in 3.1, which looks to be the next release.