# dplyr repetition within %>% operator

Tags: r, dplyr, repeat, rep

I am trying to use `rep` with `dplyr` but I do not fully understand why I can not make it work.

My data look like this. What I want is to simply repeat `dayweek` by `n` for each `id`.

```
head(dt4)

   id  dayweek n
1  1   Friday 3
2  1   Monday 3
3  1 Saturday 3
4  1   Sunday 3
5  1 Thursday 3
6  1  Tuesday 3
```

What I am trying to do is this within a `dplyr` flow

```
cbind(rep(dt4$id, dt4$n), rep(as.character(dt4$dayweek), dt4$n) )
```

which gives

```
    [,1] [,2]    
[1,] "1"  "Friday"
[2,] "1"  "Friday"
[3,] "1"  "Friday"
[4,] "1"  "Monday"
[5,] "1"  "Monday"
[6,] "1"  "Monday"
```

I do not understand why this code does not work

```
dt4 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(rep(dayweek, n))

Error: expecting a single value
```

Could someone help me with this ?

the data

```
dt4 = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), dayweek = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wedesnday"), class = "factor"), n = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), class =     "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"dayweek", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: Can't do the assignment, it shows `id` not found.

Comment: `summarise` is designed to return a single value per group. You will probably have more luck with `do`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737815/ and https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154

Comment: sorry I re-uploaded the data. It is because when i use `dput` on `dplyr` data-type (dont know the name) it doesnt not work properly

Comment: Any of these answers should work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2894775/1191259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the same result as `cbind`, we can use `do`.  As @DavidArenburg mentioned, `summarise` output a single value/row per each group combination whereas using `mutate` we get the output with the same number of rows.  But, here we are doing a different operation which can be done within the `do` environment.  In the code `.` signifies the dataset. If we want to extract the 'id' column from `dt4`, we can either use `dt4$id` or `dt4[['id']]`.  Replace the `dt4` with `.`.

```
library(dplyr)
dt4 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    do(data.frame(id=.$id, v1=rep(.$dayweek, .$n)))
#Source: local data frame [63 x 2]
#Groups: id

#  id       v1
#1   1   Friday
#2   1   Friday
#3   1   Friday
#4   1   Monday
#5   1   Monday
#6   1   Monday
#7   1 Saturday
#8   1 Saturday
#9   1 Saturday
#10  1   Sunday
#.. ..      ...
```

Or another option based on @Frank's comments would be to specify the row index generated from `rep` inside `slice` and `select` the columns that we need to keep.

```
dt4 %>%
     slice(rep(1:n(),n)) %>%
     select(-n)
```

Comment: ah interesting - could you explain me what `do` does  ? and how do you use the `.$` symbol here ? thanks Akrun

Comment: What does `group_by` do in this context? (Sorry, the dataset from the question still seems to be broken.)

Comment: @maj  In the example, there is only a single `id`, but I am guessing that in the original dataset, there might be multiple ids and we want to do the replication step within each id group

Comment: `do` is pretty terrible, performance-wise, and grouping is not necessary here. I'd go for `dt4 %>% slice(rep(1:n(),n)) %>% select(-n)`

Comment: @Frank BTW, that is a clever option.  I never thought about it.  I wonder why you didn't post that as a solution :-)

Comment: Thanks :) It's just a dplyr-flavored version of what I saw in the question I linked under the OP

Answer (score 6):

[data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) can be a useful alternative for this type of do-by operation - I find this a little easier to read:

```
library("data.table")
dt4 <- as.data.table(dt4)
head(dt4[, rep(dayweek, n), by=id], 10)
```

giving:

```
    id       V1
 1:  1   Friday
 2:  1   Friday
 3:  1   Friday
 4:  1   Monday
 5:  1   Monday
 6:  1   Monday
 7:  1 Saturday
 8:  1 Saturday
 9:  1 Saturday
10:  1   Sunday
```