# When to use "Do" function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I've learned that `Do` function is used when you want to apply a function to each group.

for example, if I want to pull top 2 rows from "A", "C", and "I" categories of variable `Index`, following syntax can be used.

```
t <- mydata %>% filter(Index %in% c("A", "C", "I")) %>% group_by(Index) %>% do(head(.,2))
```

I understand that after grouping by index, `do` function is used to compute head(.,2) for each group.

However, on some occasions, `do` is not used at all. For example, To compute mean of variable `Y2014` grouped by variable `Index`, I thought that following code should be used.

```
t <- mydata %>% group_by(Index) %>% do(summarise(Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014)))
```

however, above syntax returns error

```
Error in mean(Y2014) : object 'Y2014' not found
```

But if I remove `do` from the syntax, it returns what I exactly wanted.

```
t <- mydata %>% group_by(Index) %>% summarise(Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014))
```

I'm really confused about usage of `do` function in dplyr. It seems inconsistent to me. When should I use and not use `do` function? Why should I use `do` in the first case and not in the second case?

Comment: For `mean` you can directly use` summarise` without `do`.  For the first case also, instead of `do` use `slice` i.e. `%>% slice(1:2)`  With many other tidyverse functions like `map` etc., rarely you may have to use `do`.  One possible use case may be when you build some models by group

Comment: See e.g. **3. Syntax** / 4. `do()` in [this (excellent) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly/27718317#27718317). Another specific case for `do`: [grouped operations that result in length not equal to 1 or length of group in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737815/grouped-operations-that-result-in-length-not-equal-to-1-or-length-of-group-in-dp). Relevant [`dplyr` issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/154).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The comments under the question discuss that in many cases you can find an alternative in dplyr or associated packages that avoid the use of `do` and the examples in the question are of that sort; however, to answer the question directly rather than via alternatives:

### Differences between using do and not using it

Within the context of data frames, the key differences between using `do` and not using `do` are:

1. **No automatic insertion of dot** The code within the `do` will not have dot automatically inserted into the first argument.  For example, instead of the `do(summarise(Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014)))` code in the question one would have to write `do(summarise(., Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014)))` with a dot since the dot is not automatically inserted.  This is a consequence of `do` being the right hand side function of `%>%` rather than `summarize`.  Although this is important to understand so that we insert dot when needed if the purpose were simply to avoid automatic insertion of dot into the first argument we could alternately use brace brackets to get that effect:  `whatever %>% { myfun(arg1, arg2) }` would also *not* automatically insert dot as the first argument of the `myfun` call.
2. **respecting group_by** Only functions specifically written to respect `group_by` will do so.  There are two issues here.  (1) Only functions specifically written to respect `group_by` will be run once for each group.  `mutate`, `summarize` and `do` are examples of functions that run once per group (there are others too).  (2)  Even if the function is run once for each group there is the question of how dot is handled.  We focus on two cases (not a complete list): (i) if `do` is not used then if dot is used within a function call within an expression to an argument it will refer to the entire input ignoring `group_by`.  Presumably this is a consequence of magrittr's dot substitution rules and it not knowing anything about `group_by`.  On the other hand (ii) within `do` dot always refers to the rows of the current group.  For example, compare the output of these two and note that dot refers to 3 rows in the first case where `do` is used and all 6 rows in the second where it is not.  This is despite the fact that `summarize` respects `group_by` in that it runs once per group.

   ```
   BOD$g <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
   BOD %>% group_by(g) %>% do(summarize(., nr = nrow(.)))
   ## # A tibble: 2 x 2
   ## # Groups: g [2]
   ##       g    nr
   ##   <dbl> <int>
   ## 1  1.00     3
   ## 2  2.00     3

   BOD %>% group_by(g) %>% summarize(nr = nrow(.))
   ## # A tibble: 2 x 2
   ##       g    nr
   ##   <dbl> <int>
   ## 1  1.00     6
   ## 2  2.00     6
   ```

See `?do` for more information.

### Code from Question

Now we go through the code in the question.  As `mydata` was never defined in the question we use the first line of code below to define it to facilitate concrete examples.

```
mydata <- data.frame(Index = rep(c("A", "C", "I"), each = 3), Y2014 = 1)

mydata %>% 
       filter(Index %in% c("A", "C", "I")) %>% 
       group_by(Index) %>% 
       do(head(., 2))

## # A tibble: 6 x 2
## # Groups: Index [3]
##   Index  Y2014
##   <fctr> <dbl>
## 1 A       1.00
## 2 A       1.00
## 3 C       1.00
## 4 C       1.00
## 5 I       1.00
## 6 I       1.00
```

The code above produces 2 rows for each of the 3 groups giving 6 rows.  Had we omitted `do` then it would disregard `group_by` and produce only two rows with dot being regarded as the entire 9 rows of input, not just each group at a time.  (In this particular case dplyr provides its own alternative to `head` that avoids these problems but for sake of illustrating the general point we stick to the code in the question.)

The following code from the question generates an error because dot insertion is not done within `do` and so what ought to be the first argument of summarize, i.e. the data frame input, is missing:

```
mydata %>% 
       group_by(Index) %>% 
       do(summarise(Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014)))
## Error in mean(Y2014) : object 'Y2014' not found
```

If we remove the `do` in the above code, as in the last line of code in the question, then it works since the dot insertion is performed.  Alternately if we add the dot `do(summarise(., Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014)))` it would also work although `do` really seems superfluous in this case as `summarize` already respects `group_by` so there is no need to wrap it in `do`.

```
mydata %>% 
       group_by(Index) %>% 
       summarise(Mean_2014 = mean(Y2014))

## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   Index  Mean_2014
##   <fctr>     <dbl>
## 1 A           1.00
## 2 C           1.00
## 3 I           1.00
```

Comment: interesting. in other words, only the tidyverse-native functions will work correctly without the `do`? that is, this works completely fine `BOD %>% group_by(g) %>% do(summarize(., nr = n())` . Is the issue that nrow(.) is a `base` function?

Comment: The issue is how dot is handled. n() does not involve dot.

Comment: OK I understand. to the bottom line is the following: always use a `do` if you call a function that refers to the dataframe with a `.`. That way we are certain the dataframe being "passed" is the correct sub-group. does that make sense?

Comment: but there is also the case `gap_fits <- gap_nested %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .x)))` as in https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html . In that case, one seems to be fine with just `.x` without `do`. This is a bit inconsistent dont you think?

Comment: @NOOBIE, That example does not involve dot.

Comment: isnt `.` the same thing as `.x` ??! 

Comment: .x is the argument to a function expressed in formula notation. dot is the LHS of a pipe.

Comment: gotcha. so the issue is really coming from `magrittr`. thanks