# Accessing grouped subset in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the feeling this was already asked several times, but I can not make it run in my case. Don't know why.

I `group_by` my data frame and calculate a `mean` from values. Additionally, I marked a specific row and I want to calculate the ratio of my fresh calculated `mean` with the value of my highlighted row of the subset.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(int=c(5:1,4:1),
                 highlight=c(T,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F),
                 exp=c('a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'))

df %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(int),
            l1=nrow(.),
            ratio_mean=.[.$highlight, 'int']/mean)
```

But for some reason, `.` is not the subset of `group_by` but the complete input. Am I missing something here?

My expected output would be

```
exp    mean ratio_mean
  <fct> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 a       3         1.67
2 b       2.5       1.2
```

Comment: Use `n()` to count the number of rows in a subgroup. `.` refers to the piped input, i.e. the whole dataset

Comment: You can use `do()`: within it, `.` will refer to the subset data frame. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182815/when-to-use-do-function-in-dplyr

Comment: So how can I access the subset but not the input? Or do I need to group by `highlight` and calculate the mean with `. %>% group_by(exp) %>% summarise(mean=mean(int))`?

Comment: You can do: `ratio_mean = int[highlight]/mean`

Comment: Ahhhhhh, somehow I haven't seen this! :-)

Comment: @kath just solved it... I haven't seen this for some reason. Stupid question if I think about it now :-) Feel free to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
df %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(int),
            l1 = n(),
            ratio_mean = int[highlight] / mean)
```

But what's going wrong with your solution?

- `nrow(.)` counts the number of rows of your whole input dataframe, wherase `n()` counts only the rows per group
- `.[.$highlight, 'int']/mean` here again you use the whole input dataframe and subset using the highlight column, but it get's divided by the correct group mean. Actually you are returning two values here as two rows of your original df have a `highlight = TRUE`. This causes a nasty `NA`-column name.

To save it, we could use `do()` as suggested by @MikkoMarttila, but this gets a little bit clunky:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(exp) %>% 
  do(summarise(., mean = mean(.$int),
               l1 = nrow(.),
               ratio_mean = .$int[.$highlight] / mean))
```

**Original output**

```
df %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(int),
            l1=nrow(.),
            ratio_mean=.[.$highlight, 'int']/mean)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   exp    mean    l1 ratio_mean$    NA
#   <fct> <dbl> <int>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a       3       9        1.67   2  
# 2 b       2.5     9        1      1.2
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow didn't realised that within summary, I can directly assess the columns... :-) Maybe it was to early today ;-)